# how to schedule notifications using flutter and firebase cloud messaging

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

im working on a project using flutter and django rest framework, I want notify the user of the app daily like a remainder to do his daily missions

my problem is how to schedule the notification daily.
i have hosted my django project in pythonanywhere.

Comment: fetch timetamp from db and schedule notification using flutter local notifications

Comment: @raghav042 perhaps you could make this an answer rather than a comment so the OP can accept it.

Comment: If the time for the notification is determined in the app itself, did you consider using a local notification instead of FCM. E.g. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications